# openvpn routing script failing to execute when called by openvpn

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

Hi all im following this scripts here [deluge-vpn](https://github.com/bendikro/deluge-vpn/blob/master/user_filter/vpn_routing_table.sh)
the script fails at the routing scipt below, when its called by openvpn.
If i start openvpn without the up script and execute the script seperatly it runs fine. Sorry if i havent set it out correctl but any help would be a great help.

heres the error

```
/etc/openvpn/link_up_user_filter.sh  
Device "tun0" does not exist.  
Error: an inet address is expected rather than "table".  
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2  
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/rp_filter: No such file or directory
```

here is the results of it running correctly

```
Nov 17 16:16:46 hp-server openvpn[48795]: /usr/sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500  
Nov 17 16:16:46 hp-server openvpn[48795]: /usr/sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.4.1.252/16 broadcast 10.4.255.255    
Nov 17 16:16:51 hp-server openvpn[48795]: /usr/sbin/ip route add 213.152.161.116/32 via 192.168.1.254  
Nov 17 16:16:51 hp-server openvpn[48795]: /usr/sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.4.0.1  
Nov 17 16:16:51 hp-server openvpn[48795]: /usr/sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.4.0.1
Nov 17 16:16:51 hp-server openvpn[48795]: Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SRC_DIR="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
if [[ ! -d "$SRC_DIR" ]]; then SRC_DIR="$PWD"; fi
source "$SRC_DIR/vpn_base.sh"

VPN_IP=`get_nic_ip $VPNIF`
# Remove old table

ip route flush table $TABLE_ID

# Add rule to use TABLE_ID for marked packets
if [[ `ip rule list | grep -c $MARK_ID` == 0 ]]; then
ip rule add from all fwmark $MARK_ID lookup $TABLE_ID
fi

ip route replace default via $VPN_IP table $TABLE_ID
ip route append default via 127.0.0.1 dev lo table $TABLE_ID
ip route flush cache

# Set reverse path source validation to lose mode
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=2
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.$VPNIF.rp_filter=2
```

openvpn.conf as requested

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote *.*.*.* *
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo no
route-delay 5
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 5
script-security 2


#up and down scripts to be executed when VPN starts or stops
up /etc/openvpn/link_up_user_filter.sh
```

Comment: show your openvpn config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt get this script to funcion properly so moved onto seperate network namespacess which worked just the way i wanted.
[OpenVPN for a single application on Linux](https://schnouki.net/posts/2014/12/12/openvpn-for-a-single-application-on-linux/)